# Decrypting AES256 strings from NSString NOT NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, encryption, commoncrypto

I am trying to work with `AES256` to send and receive strings from an iPhone app to server and back.

Using the following I can successfully encrypt a string and decrypt a string with the following code:-

```
// Encryption Methods
NSString *theStringToDecrypt = @"{\"String\":\"This is a string\"}";
NSData *theEncodedString = [theStringToDecrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // NSUTF8 Encrypt the string
NSData *encryptedData = [theEncodedString AES256EncryptWithKey:theKey]; // Encrypt to AES-256
NSData *decryptedData = [encryptedData AES256DecryptWithKey:theKey]; // Decrypt from AES-256
NSString *theDecodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // NSUTF8 Decode the string
NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // NSUTF8 Decode the string
NSLog(@"theDecryptedKey=%@ | theEncryptedKey=%@",theString,theDecodedString);
```

So, this grabs a string, converts to `NSData` using `UTF`8 encoding then encrypts the data using `AES256`. It then decrypts the `NSData` and converts back to string.

This works as it should and successfully encrypts/decrypts the string.

The issue that I am having is that from the server I get the data back as a decrypted string so need to pass a string to `AES256DecryptWithKey` to simply decrypt it but `AES256DecryptWithKe`y only works with `NSData`.

This causes issues since I already have an encrypted string so converting to data then encrypting to `AES` includes the UTF8 encoding so I am effectively only converting the `UTF8` String back to the decrypted string.

Am I missing something simple here or there a darker force at work?

Comment: It depends on how the server encodes it into a string.

Comment: It will encode however we want it to. At the moment we are testing all of this so atm I am not even using the server side and instead have an NSString of the decrypted string I am testing with!

Comment: You said that the above code works though.  Why don't you just get the data out of the encrypted string the same way you did for the decrypted one.

Comment: so I  have a decrypted "string" and if I convert that to NSData it uses encoding of NSUTF8 so I then decrypt that using AES256EncryptWithKey and it is invalid since the UTF8 has added stuff to the data.

Comment: That's why I asked how your server is going to make the string.  If it just makes a string using the literal UTF-8 data then there is no problem.  The above code sample working is testament to that.  UTF-8 encoding doesn't "add" anything, it merely transforms it into an array of bytes.  If you look at it, you will notice a 1-to-1 matchup between bytes and letters (for ASCII, anyway).  If your server cannot do that, then you will have to send it using Base64.

Comment: Going to try Base64 now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not treat binary data (the ciphertext) as UTF-8. The ciphertext is not a string.

If your protocol does not handle binary data, you have to convert the ciphertext to a string using a binary-to-text encoding, like Base64.

Comment: Right, so Base64 may be the solution. Will have a look at this now! Thanks